# Problemas con Jquery en un buscador como cambiar la orientación cuando abre el buscador

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hola estoy teniendo problemas con este ejemplo [ejemplo](http://cssdeck.com/labs/yzks7boo) de buscador que estoy aplicando a mi sitio, lo que estoy tratando de querer hacer es que el buscador empuje los elementos de la izquierda en ves de empujar a los de la derecha. lo estoy aplicando a este ejemplo que subo en imagen donde quiero que el buscado desplace hacia la izq a los otros elementos, si es necesario que suba el codigo que uso en este ejemplo lo adjunto [image]

```js
  ( function() {

 $('#btn-search').on('click', function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  $('#search').animate({width: 'toggle'}).focus();

 });

} () );
```

```css
  @charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

/* ---------- FONTAWESOME ---------- */
/* ---------- http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/ ---------- */
/* ---------- http://weloveiconfonts.com/ ---------- */

@import url(http://weloveiconfonts.com/api/?family=fontawesome);

a[class*="fontawesome-"]:before,
span[class*="fontawesome-"]:before {
 display: block;
 font-family: 'FontAwesome', sans-serif;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

/* ---------- GENERAL ---------- */

body {
 background: #ccc;
 font: 87.5%/1.5em 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 margin: 0;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
}

button {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-transform: none;
}

button::-moz-focus-inner {
 border: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

fieldset {
 border: 0;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

input {
 border: 0;
 font-family: inherit;
 font-size: 100%;
 line-height: inherit;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

input:focus {
 outline: none;
}

input[type="search"] {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

/* ---------- CLASSES ---------- */

.clearfix { *zoom: 1; }
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
 content: "";
 display: table; 
}
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }

.container {
 left: 50%;
 margin: -17px 0 0 -186px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 width: 372px;
}

/* ---------- TOOLBAR ---------- */

.toolbar {
 color: #fff;
}

.toolbar li {
 float: left;
}

.toolbar li:first-child a { border-radius: .5em 0 0 .5em; }
.toolbar li:last-child button { border-radius: 0 .5em .5em 0; }

.toolbar a,
.toolbar input[type="search"],
.toolbar button {
 background: #3598db;
 color: #fff;
 display: block;
 padding: .5em 1em;
 position: relative;
}

.toolbar a:hover,
.toolbar input[type="search"]:hover,
.toolbar input[type="search"]:focus,
.toolbar button:hover {
 background: #2a80b9;
}

.toolbar input[type="search"] {
 display: none;
 height: 21px;
 width: 177px;
}

.toolbar input[type="search"]::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #fff; }
.toolbar input[type="search"]::-moz-placeholder { color: #fff; opacity: 1; }
.toolbar input[type="search"]:-moz-placeholder { color: #fff; opacity: 1; }
.toolbar input[type="search"]:-ms-input-placeholder { color: #fff; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <form>
   
   <fieldset>
    
    <ul class="toolbar clearfix">

     <li><a href="#" class="fontawesome-heart"></a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="fontawesome-eye-open"></a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="fontawesome-comment"></a></li>
     <li><input type="search" id="search" placeholder="What are you looking for?"></li>
     <li><button type="submit" id="btn-search"><span class="fontawesome-search"></span></button></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="fontawesome-comment"></a></li>

    </ul>

   </fieldset>

  </form>

 </div> <!-- end container -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la opción mas simple es simplemente invertir el orden de de los elementos del menu y hacer-los flotar hacia la derecha.

html:

```
<ul class="toolbar clearfix">

  <li><button type="submit" id="btn-search"><span class="fontawesome-search"></span></button></li>
  <li><input type="search" id="search" placeholder="What are you looking for?"></li>        
  <li><a href="#" class="fontawesome-comment"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="fontawesome-eye-open"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="fontawesome-heart"></a></li>

</ul>
```

css:

```
.toolbar li:first-child button { border-radius: 0 .5em .5em 0; }
.toolbar li:last-child a { border-radius: .5em 0 0 .5em; }

.toolbar li {
  float:right;
}
```

También habría que modificar los radios para que coincidan con la nueva posición de los elementos.

http://cssdeck.com/labs/full/cvckva5x

Comment: gracias probé tambien pero no era lo que quería, termine usando otra cosa.